# Kubernetes service loadbalancer, turn off exposed ports

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-elb, kubernetes-service

Is there a way to control k8s service with type Loadbalancer to control exposed ports on external LB.

While you creating a service in k8s with type LB, this is how the network connection looks like

[image]

Basically, I want to define k8s service, with type load balancer, and it should open SSL terminated lb endpoint with port 443, while internally on the same k8s service it should accept the HTTP calls.

Note: I can get it done using two service definition, but checking if I can handle this using single service using any annotation or some other configs.

Answer (score -2):

This issue depends on the type of LB you intend on using. If you're running your cluster on AWS, you can use [this](https://kubernetes-on-aws.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/tls-termination.html#create-a-service) solution to achieve what you're after.